# How can I throw an error if --shell-escape isn't enabled?

Tags: errors, shell-escape

I'm writing a document that makes heavy use of `\includesvg`; that in turn requires `--shell-escape` so it can call inkscape.  I'm compiling (as always) from the terminal, and don't really want to alias `pdflatex` to `pdflatex --shell-escape`, but I keep forgetting to use the argument.

Is there a way in my document source to get an error if it's not enabled? I specifically don't want a warning, I want compilation to stop on this but not on the many "PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with page group included in a single page" warnings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lower level methods

but

```
\usepackage{shellesc}
```

will give you  `\ShellEscapeStatus` which is 0 (disabled) 1 (allowed) 2 (default=restricted)

so

```
\ifnum\ShellEscapeStatus=1 \else
\PackageError{mypackage}{use shell escape}{or else}
\fi
```

Comment: A rare immediate acceptance from me - that's ideal.  One thing to note is that it needs a recent version of `shellesc` (I seem to be on TL2017 and the version in that doesn't define `\ShellEscapeStatus`).

Comment: @ChrisH oops yes I probably should have remembered that (since I wrote the thing:-)